# Baseball XML to SQL query - optimize

Tags: sql-server, xml

source data looks comes from the following, freely available XML files describing major league baseball games.

http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_2013/month_04/day_09/gid_2013_04_09_atlmlb_miamlb_1/inning/

I have created a SQL Server table that contains a row for every GamePK/inning, with an XML column named PBP. Each file in the folder above becomes a row in this table. The query below is my attempt to parse the XML into a record set.  It works but is very slow for a large number of rows, and very repetitive - seems like there should be a better way to do this without the UNION clause.  Any help in improving/optimizing is appreciated

```
select 
 i.GamePK
 ,inn.value('@num', 'int') as inning
 ,itop.value('1', 'int') as IsTop
 ,itop.value('@num', 'int') as abNum
 ,itop.value('@batter', 'int') as batter
--  clip

 ,itoppit.value('@des', 'varchar(32)') as pitdesc
 ,itoppit.value('@id', 'int') as seq
 ,itoppit.value('@type', 'varchar(8)') as pittype
-- clip 

 from tblInnings i
       cross apply PBP.nodes('/inning') as inn(inn)
       cross apply inn.nodes('top/atbat') as itop(itop)
       cross apply itop.nodes('pitch') as itoppit(itoppit)
union 
select 
 i.GamePK
 ,inn.value('@num', 'int') as inning
 ,ibot.value('0', 'int') as IsTop
 ,ibot.value('@num', 'int') as abNum
 ,ibot.value('@batter', 'int') as batter
-- clip 

 ,ibotpit.value('@des', 'varchar(32)') as pitdesc
 ,ibotpit.value('@id', 'int') as seq
 ,ibotpit.value('@type', 'varchar(8)') as pittype
--clip

 from tblInnings i
       cross apply PBP.nodes('/inning') as inn(inn)
       cross apply inn.nodes('bottom/atbat') as ibot(ibot)
       cross apply ibot.nodes('pitch') as ibotpit(ibotpit)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent version of SQL Server, there's a new column data type (XML).

You can apply xpath to it, making querying the column much easier.

Instead of trying to store the XML as a string in your DB, I'd suggest you actually store it as XML, and treat it as XML.

There is a learning curve. You'll need to be familiar with XPATH, but it's not rocket science.

an example:

```
SELECT Id, PartitionMonth, EmailAddress, AcquisitionCodeId, FieldValues.value('
declare namespace s="http://domain.com/FieldValues.xsd";
data(/s:FieldValues/s:item/@value)[1]', 'varchar(200)')
FROM Leads.Leads WITH (NOLOCK)
 WHERE Id = 190708
```

Another example retrieving values by key:

```
SELECT r.EmailAddress, ar.Ip, ar.DateLog, 
  ar.FieldValues.value('
  declare namespace s="http://domain.com/FieldValues.xsd";
  data(/s:FieldValues/s:item[@key="First Name"]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(20)') FirstName,
  ar.FieldValues.value('
  declare namespace s="http://domain.com/FieldValues.xsd";
  data(/s:FieldValues/s:item[@key="Last Name"]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(20)') LastName
FROM Records.Records r WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN Records.AcquisitionRecords ar WITH (NOLOCK) ON r.Id = ar.Id
WHERE ar.AcquisitionCodeId IN (19, 21, 30, 34, 36)
AND ar.DateLog BETWEEN '1-mar-09' AND '31-mar-09'
```

A good place to get started on XML in SQL Server
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189887(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Note that it will all depend on how you want to access your data. If you need fast lookups, you'll want to extract your data and store it in its own column and index it properly. XML is meant for generic data storage.